# background image/video issue in blender vfx

Tags: compositing-nodes

I was following one youtube tutorial and tried vfx green background.

I have selected the mask and now in compositing mode i want to add a new background. But, i am unable to do that . Please suggest me the menu to do that .
I am a beginner in Blender vfx.

I have attached the screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and add one more movie clip, load your background footage in that movie clip angle, and finally you can connect it with viewer